# Modal fade-out background case sensitive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I am using angular with foundation and using the following for opening modals:

```
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: templateUrl,
      controller: 'CollectionTileController',
      resolve: {
        tiles: function () {
          return collectionTiles;
        },
        collectionTile: function () {
          return menuitem;
        }
      },
      windowClass: menuitem.modalClass || 'reveal-modal-medium'
    });
```

It is working fine but I have a problem concerning case-sensitive greying out of the background (see images)

[image: modal fade-out]
[image: modal without fade-out]

We do have a CSS-file where the class can be overritten to change the color.

```
.reveal-modal-bg,
.reveal-modal-frame {
   display: none;
   visibility: visible;
   position: fixed;
   //for overriding the background so it won't fade grey
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```

Does anybody know I can override the foundation class .reveal-modal-bg to be case-sensitive? The modal frame is generated and this class is added (see html below). So I can override the .reveal-modal-bg class but it would effect all modals in the application.

```
<div class="reveal-modal-bg fade in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-click="close($event)" style="display: block;" modal-backdrop></div>
```